# Is it possible to place Grafana annotations not at the bottom of a panel?

Tags: graph, grafana

Is there a way to place Grafana annotations on the `y` axis anywhere that isn't the bottom? (*i.e.* where `y≠0`)?

Currently, graphs show up like this:

[image: grafana graph, with three annotations at the bottom]

Ideally, we want to be able to bring the annotations to where the rest of the graph is, where `y` is variable and follows the values from a certain field. Even having the annotations at the top (say, `y=100`) would be good.

Looking at [documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/annotations/) hasn't helped a lot so far.

Answer (score 1):

No. That is not possible - unless you will customize Grafana source code.